# How to use Zip operator of kotlin flow in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, kotlin-flow

In my application I want combine two deferent API with `ZIP` operator of Kotlin `flow`.!
**Api 1** is **Movies list** and **Api 2** is **genres list**! 
I want loaded each 2 Apis in one time, for this I used `zip` operator!
My work is true? Can I combine 2 deferent Apis with them?

**ApiServices :**

```
interface ApiServices {
    @GET("movies")
    suspend fun moviesList(): Response<MoviesList>

    @GET("genres")
    suspend fun genresList(): Response<GenresList>
}
```

**Repository class:**

```
class Repository @Inject constructor(private val api: ApiServices) {

    suspend fun moviesList(): Flow<Response<MovieList>> {
        return flow {
            emit(api.moviesList(1))
        }
    }

    suspend fun genresList(): Flow<Response<GenresList>> {
        return flow {
            emit(api.genresList())
        }
    }
}
```

I know show error for add deferent model class in moviesList !

But I want know how can I use `Zip` operator for combine 2 deferent Apis?

Comment: your flows emit 1 element, why not keep them as `suspend fun`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `combine(flow1,flow2)` method to combine the `flow` and zipping your api response using `zip` , for example :

```kotlin
class ViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {

    val moviesFlow = repository.moviesList()
    val genresFlow = repository.genresList()

    fun loadMoviesAndGenres() : Flow<List<Pair<Type1,Type2>>> = combine(moviesFlow, genresFlow) { movieList: Response<MovieList>, genreList:Response<GenresList> ->
       val movies = movies.body()?.data
       val genres = genres.body()
       return@combine movies?.zip(genres)
    }
}
```

**How to use `zip`** :

```kotlin
val listMovieTittle = listOf("avanger", "conjuring", "other")
val listGenre = listOf("action", "horror", "fantasy", "thriller")

val result1 : List<Pair<String,String>> = listMovieTittle .zip(listGenre)
println(result1 ) // [(avanger, action), (bconjuring, horror), (other, fantasy)]

val result2  : List<String> = listMovieTittle .zip(listGenre) { a, b -> "$a + $b" }
println(result2) // [avanger + action, conjuring + horror, other + fantasy]
```

Comment: @Dr.KeyOk basically your `genres` of type is not an `iterable` a.k.a not a `List` or `Array` , **`zip` method only work if both of them are List/Array**